# Angular 15 Material - CSS for Disabled Form Fields

Tags: css, angular15, angular-material-15

Since our update to Angular 15, end users have been upset about the opacity of disabled form fields. I have been trying without success to access the class structure in css.

I have tried everything from:

```
  .mat-mdc-form-field, .mat-mdc-form-field-type-mat-input, .mat-mdc-form-field-label-always-float, .mat-form-field-disabled, .mat-form-field-appearance-outline, {
color: rgba(0,0,0, 1.0);
```

}

To:

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-disabled {    color: rgba(0,0,0, 1.0); }
```

Nothing seems to crack into the base css. When I select elements within the browser console I cannot even seem to get any css classes which hint at even part of a disabled field, even when the element I select is in fact a disabled form field.

This is the first version our theme level opacity changes have no worked.

Can someone please point me to what I am missing?